# Use @click method with select tag to change value on a computed property

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

What I'm trying to do is:

1. Input an emotion with the text box and rate the intensity of the emotion with the select box. The blue button adds emotion.
2. In the rerate section I would like to rerate the intensity of that emotion.

In the rerate, I'm looping through a computed property `rerateEmotions` that has an array of objects that contains `emotion` and `intensity` properties. What I'd like to do is change the intensity for each emotion on the computed property with the select tag:

**Edit**

Okay, I found out I need to change the `@click` to `@change` on the rerate `<select>`

Now I just want to figure out how to have a separate rating from the "rate emotion" and rerate emotion" areas.

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: function() {
    return {
      emotion: "",
      intensity: null,
      newIntensity: null,
      emotionIntensity: []
    };
  },
  computed: {
    rerateEmotions() {
      return this.emotionIntensity;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    rerateIntensity(id) {
      return (this.rerateEmotions[id].intensity = this.newIntensity);
    },
    openEmotion(id) {
      this.emotionId = id;
    },
    addEmotionIntensity() {
      var emotionIntensity = {
        emotion: this.emotion,
        intensity: this.intensity
      };
      this.emotionIntensity.push(emotionIntensity);
      this.emotion = "";
      this.intensity = null;
    },
    removeEmotion(id) {
      if (id > -1) {
        this.emotionIntensity.splice(id, 1);
      }
    },
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">

  <div class="row mb-3 pr-4">
    <div class="col-6">
      <h1>Rate</h1>
      <input v-model="emotion" type="text" placeholder="Enter emotion here." class="form-control" id="basic-url" aria-describedby="basic-addon3">
    </div>
    <div class="col-5 select-outline">
      <select class="mdb-select md-form md-outline colorful-select dropdown-primary" v-model="intensity">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Rate Emotion</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="9">9</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <button @click="addEmotionIntensity()" type="button" class="col-1 btn btn-primary">+</button>
  </div>

  <ul>
    <li v-for="(emotion, index) in emotionIntensity">
      <b>{{emotion.emotion}} : {{emotion.intensity}}</b>
      <button type="button" @click="removeEmotion(index)">
        X
      </button>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <hr>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1"><h5>Rerate</h5></label>

    <li v-for="(emotion, index) in rerateEmotions">
      <b>{{emotion.emotion}} : {{emotion.intensity}}</b>
      <select class="mdb-select md-form md-outline colorful-select dropdown-primary" @change="rerateIntensity(index)">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Rate Emotion</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="9">9</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
      </select>
    </li>
    <hr>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need two intensity rating then you could just have two properties on each object. e.g. `intensity` and `newIntensity`. In the example below I've initialised both to the same value when an entry is first created but the second property could be left empty if that's preferred.

The computed property `rerateEmotions` didn't seem to be doing anything so I've removed it in favour of using `emotionIntensity` directly. Perhaps the intent was to create a copy but using a computed property won't have that effect, it will just be the same array.

For the re-rate dropdown I've used `v-model`, though there's no reason why you couldn't use an event listener if you prefer. The key thing is that I'm using the `newIntensity` property for that second value.

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: function() {
    return {
      emotion: "",
      intensity: null,
      newIntensity: null,
      emotionIntensity: []
    };
  },
  methods: {
    openEmotion(id) {
      this.emotionId = id;
    },
    addEmotionIntensity() {
      var emotionIntensity = {
        emotion: this.emotion,
        intensity: this.intensity,
        newIntensity: this.intensity
      };
      this.emotionIntensity.push(emotionIntensity);
      this.emotion = "";
      this.intensity = null;
    },
    removeEmotion(id) {
      if (id > -1) {
        this.emotionIntensity.splice(id, 1);
      }
    },
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">

  <div class="row mb-3 pr-4">
    <div class="col-6">
      <h1>Rate</h1>
      <input v-model="emotion" type="text" placeholder="Enter emotion here." class="form-control" id="basic-url" aria-describedby="basic-addon3">
    </div>
    <div class="col-5 select-outline">
      <select class="mdb-select md-form md-outline colorful-select dropdown-primary" v-model="intensity">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Rate Emotion</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="9">9</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <button @click="addEmotionIntensity()" type="button" class="col-1 btn btn-primary">+</button>
  </div>

  <ul>
    <li v-for="(emotion, index) in emotionIntensity">
      <b>{{emotion.emotion}} : {{emotion.intensity}}</b>
      <button type="button" @click="removeEmotion(index)">
        X
      </button>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <hr>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1"><h5>Rerate</h5></label>

    <li v-for="(emotion, index) in emotionIntensity">
      <b>{{emotion.emotion}} : {{emotion.newIntensity}}</b>
      <select v-model="emotion.newIntensity" class="mdb-select md-form md-outline colorful-select dropdown-primary">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Rate Emotion</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="9">9</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
      </select>
    </li>
    <hr>
  </div>
</div>
```